# Php problemas ao escrever variavel em arquivo de texto

Tags: php, html

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma pagina de registro para um micro jogo de que vamos testar na sala de aula e como não sei muito de php estou com problemas, eu criei um arquivo que pega os valores dos campos de texto e depois salva em arquivos txt em uma pasta com mesmo nome de usuário e id, porém tenho três problemas.

1 - Ele gera os arquivos mesmo os campos input estando vazios.

2 - Ele não escreve dentro dos arquivos o conteúdo dos campos.

3 - Não está criando o arquivo na pasta ids \ onde ficaria o id de todos os usuários separadamente e seriam comparados dentro da pasta afim de ver se encontra um id existente.

Oque é essa pagina ?

è um registrador de usuário php onde registra o usuário e pode alterar os dados se for repetido o nome de usuário e id permitindo assim atualizar os dados de um usuário já existente.

por que não um banco de dados ?

Por que não é um jogo grande e a ideia é não precisar de chamadar sql ou algo do tipo mostrando um jeito alternativo, de fazer a função.

Observações: Os arquivos progresso1.txt até progresso7.txt gravam dados, mas o progresso8.txt e os demais arquivos de texto não recebem os dados dos campos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="wnameth=device-wnameth, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>REGISRY</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/query/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/popcss.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/modalJS.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/svg/logo.svg" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.min.css">
  
<script src="./js/blockjsmin.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/blockstyle.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="layer"></div>
<!-- ! Body -->
<a class="skip-link sr-only" href="#skip-target">Skip to content</a>
<div class="page-flex">
  <!-- ! Snameebar -->
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <!-- ! Main nav -->
    <nav class="main-nav--bg">
  <div class="container main-nav">
    <div class="main-nav-start">
    
    </div>
    <div class="main-nav-end">
      <button class="snameebar-toggle transparent-btn" title="Menu" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle menu</span>
        <span class="icon menu-toggle--gray" aria-hnameden="true"></span>
      </button>
    
   <b>Salvando dados da conta</b>
      <div class="notification-wrapper">
        <button class="gray-circle-btn dropdown-btn" title="To messages" type="button" style="display:none;">
          <span class="sr-only">To messages</span>
          <span class="icon notification active" aria-hnameden="true"></span>
        </button>
        
  </div>
</nav>


    <!-- ! Main -->
    <main class="main users chart-page" name="skip-target">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="main-title"></h2>
        <div class="row stat-cards">
          <!--div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
             </div-->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <article class="stat-cards-item">
              <!--div class="stat-cards-icon warning">
                <i data-feather="file" aria-hnameden="true"></i>
              </div-->
              <div class="stat-cards-info">
                <!--p class="stat-cards-info__num">Alfabetização de Cegos</p>
                <p class="stat-cards-info__title">
                
                
                
                </p-->
            <?php
        
        
        
 //Registra o Usuario
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     
     /*Php 5.6.2  Code By : Michael S. author*/

            //globais
            $username = $_POST['usernamesave'];
            $userxp = $_POST['userxp'];
            $userid = $_POST['userid'];
            $userlevel = $_POST['userlevel'];
            $usermail = $_POST['usermail'];
            $progresso1 = $_POST['userprog1'];
            $progresso2 = $_POST['userprog2'];
            $progresso3 = $_POST['userprog3'];
            $progresso4 = $_POST['userprog4'];
            $progresso5 = $_POST['userprog5'];
            $progresso6 = $_POST['userprog6'];
            $progresso7 = $_POST['userprog7'];
            $progresso8 = $_POST['userprog8'];
            $proceed = $_POST['proceed'];

        
            
            //variaveis concatenadas nome com email e id do campo digitado
            $namenamef = $username  . '_' . $userid;
            $namemail = $username . $usermail;

            //Cria pasta do usuario
            if (!file_exists("usersaccounts/$namenamef/")) {
            mkdir('usersaccounts/'.$namenamef, 0777, true);
            }
            
            
            //generate a rand value
            $randger= rand() % 9000 + 1000;
            $randfix = $randger;
            //verify into folder if existe into any file the name , if yes then generete new random
        //  $tokens = ['_twitter_sess', 'ct0', 'auth_token'];
            $tokens = $randger;
                
            //verifica se o id exite em algum  arquivo da pasta ele gera o arquivo se sim ele gera outro numero.
            foreach (glob(getcwd() . './usersaccounts/ids/*.txt') as $file) {
            $pointer = fopen($file, 'r');
            while (!feof($pointer)) {
            $line = fgets($pointer);

            foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            if (strpos($line, $token) !== false) {
                //$row[] = $line;
                $randger= rand() % 9000 + 1000;
                $randfix = $randger;
                break;
                }else{
                $fp = fopen('/usersaccounts/ids/' . $namemail. '.txt' , 'w');
                fwrite($fp, $randfix);
                fclose($fp);
                }
                
                }
            }}
            
            // não está registrando valor
            if ($username = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o usuario!');</script>";
            }else{
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/username.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $username);
                fclose($fp);
            if ($userxp = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o xp !');</script>";
            }else{
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/xp.txt' , 'w');
                 if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $userxp);
                fclose($fp);
                
            if ($username = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o nome !');</script>";
            }else{
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/name.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $username);
                fclose($fp);
            if ($userlevel = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o level !');</script>";
            }else{
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/level.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $userlevel);
                fclose($fp);
            if ($usermail = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o mail !');</script>";
            }else{
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/email.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $usermail);
                fclose($fp);
                
                
                if ($progresso1 && $progresso2 && $progresso3 && $progresso4 && $progresso5 && $progresso6 && $progresso7 && $progresso8 = null){
                echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o progress !');</script>";
            }else{
                
                //cria a pasta progress
                if (!file_exists("usersaccounts/$namenamef/progress/")) {
                mkdir('usersaccounts/'. $namenamef . '/progress/', 0777, true);
                }
            
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso1.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso1);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso2.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso2);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso3.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso3);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso4.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso4);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso5.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso5);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso6.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso6);
                fclose($fp);
                
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso7.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso7);
                fclose($fp);
                // não está registrando valor
                $fp = fopen('usersaccounts/' . $namenamef . '/progress/progresso8.txt' , 'w');
                if ($fp == false) die('Não foi possível salvar o registro.'); //a
                fwrite($fp, $progresso8);
                fclose($fp);
                
                
                
            }
            }
            }       
            }   
            }   
            }
            
            
            
            


}


            ?>
                
                
                <div class="container">
        <!--h2 class="text-center"><p class="stat-cards-info__num">Salvando Mostrando</p></h2><hr-->
        <div class="row">
        <form  method="post">
        
        <label for="usernamesave">Nome de usuario:</label>
        <input name="usernamesave" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userxp">Minha Experiêcia:</label>
        <input name="userxp" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userid">Meu Tagname User:</label>
        <input name="userid" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userlevel">Level da Minha Conta:</label>
        <input name="userlevel" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="usermail">Meu email pessoal:</label>
        <input name="usermail" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog1">Meu uso Progress01:</label>
        <input name="userprog1" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog2">Meu uso Progress02:</label>
        <input name="userprog2" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog3">Meu uso Progress03:</label>
        <input name="userprog3" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog4">Meu uso Progress04:</label>
        <input name="userprog4" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog5">Meu uso Progress05:</label>
        <input name="userprog5" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog6">Meu uso Progress06:</label>
        <input name="userprog6" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog7">Meu uso Progress07:</label>
        <input name="userprog7" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="userprog8">Meu uso Progress08:</label>
        <input name="userprog8" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        <label for="proceed">Proseeguir pra sav</label>
        <input name="proceed" type="text"></input>
        <hr>
        
        
 <p><input name="submit"  type="submit" /></p>
</form>
        
        
    <!--textarea name="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
    </textarea-->
        
                
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          
            <div class="users-table table-wrapper">
             
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div-->
      </div>
    </main>
    
    
    
   
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Chart library -->
<script src="./plugins/chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- Icons library -->
<script src="plugins/feather.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts -->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>


            
<!-- ordered list -->
    
      

    </div>
                
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
 
    <!-- mascara para cobrir o site --> 
        <div name="mascara"></div>
<!--<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.0/vnameeo.js"></script>-->
        
        
        </body>

 
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema provavelmente está ocorrendo por conta da forma na qual o seu if foi implementado. Você está utilizando o operador de atribuição '=' no lugar do operador de comparação '==' ou '==='

Veja o trecho de código abaixo como exemplo:

```
if ($username = null){
    echo "<script>alert('Erro ao salvar o usuario!');</script>";
}else
```

Dentro do IF, você está atribuindo o valor 'null' a variável $username, eliminando o valor original da variável $username e deixando o valor 'NULL' a ser interpretado pelo IF, fazendo com que o código sempre entre no else, sempre gravando valores sem dados.

alterar os operadores pelo seu código deve resolver o problema.